# How to remove field from response, Gorm - Postgres

Tags: go, go-gorm, goland

I'm using GORM in a Go application to retrieve a user and their associated clients. However, I'm facing an issue where an unwanted field, assignee_user, is being included in the JSON response when using GORM's Preload function.

Here's my code:

```golang
// Service
func GetUser(userId string) models.User {
    var user models.User

    database.DB.Preload("Clients").First(&user, userId)

    return user
}

// User.go
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name         string   `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"name"`
    LastName     string   `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"lastname"`
    Username     string   `gorm:"size:255; not null; unique" json:"username"`
    Password     string   `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"password"`
    Email        string   `gorm:"size:255; not null; unique" json:"email"`
    Phone        string   `gorm:"size:255" json:"phone"`
    Status       int      `gorm:"size:1; not null; default:0" json:"status"`
    Clients      []Client `gorm:"foreignKey:AssigneeUserID" json:"clients"`
    ClientsCount int      `gorm:"default:0" json:"clients_count"`
}

// Client.go
type Client struct {
    helpers.Model
    Name           string  `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"name"`
    LastName       string  `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"lastname"`
    Phone          string  `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"phone"`
    Address        string  `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"address"`
    AmountApproved float64 `gorm:"size:255; not null" json:"amount_approved"`
    Status         int     `gorm:"size:1; not null; default:0" json:"status"`

    AssigneeUserID uint `gorm:"not null" json:"assignee_user_id"`
    AssigneeUser   User `gorm:"foreignKey:AssigneeUserID" json:"assignee_user"` // This is the field i don't want in the response when i query the user, but i do want the field if i query the client
}
```

currently i'm getting this response

```json
{
    "id": 987,
    "createdAt": "2023-10-15T08:30:45.123456Z",
    "updatedAt": "2023-12-05T15:20:30.987654Z",
    "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
    "name": "Eleanor",
    "lastname": "Anderson",
    "username": "eanderson",
    "password": "$2a$14$jg9X5ZiN7BjzJ6WnTgT4hOfjBvhwv8I7FfquKtXeHmOdpy40sZurS",
    "email": "eleanor.anderson@example.com",
    "phone": "+1234567890",
    "status": 1,
    "clients": [
        {
            "id": 102,
            "createdAt": "2023-11-20T10:15:30.987654Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-11-22T09:45:30.123456Z",
            "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "name": "Alice",
            "lastname": "Johnson",
            "phone": "9876543210",
            "address": "456 Elm St",
            "amount_approved": 500,
            "status": 1,
            "assignee_user_id": 987,
            "assignee_user": {
                "id": 0,
                "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "name": "",
                "lastname": "",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "email": "",
                "phone": "",
                "status": 0,
                "clients": null,
                "clients_count": 0
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 103,
            "createdAt": "2023-11-25T14:20:45.123456Z",
            "updatedAt": "2023-11-28T18:30:15.987654Z",
            "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
            "name": "Bob",
            "lastname": "Smith",
            "phone": "5551234567",
            "address": "789 Oak St",
            "amount_approved": 750,
            "status": 1,
            "assignee_user_id": 987,
            "assignee_user": {
                "id": 0,
                "createdAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "updatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "deletedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                "name": "",
                "lastname": "",
                "username": "",
                "password": "",
                "email": "",
                "phone": "",
                "status": 0,
                "clients": null,
                "clients_count": 0
            }
        }
    ],
    "clients_count": 2
}
```

I've tried using Preload and Select functions to exclude the assignee_user field but haven't been successful. How can I preload the associated clients without including the assignee_user field in the JSON response?

Any help or guidance on how to achieve this exclusion while still loading the associated clients using GORM would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

i have tried this as well:

```golang
func GetUser(userId string) models.User {
    var user models.User

    database.DB.Preload("Clients").Omit("Clients.AssigneeUser").First(&user, userId)

    return user
}
```

Comment: can you check adding **sql:"-"** tag on the field?

Comment: But that will delete the field for all queries, right? So my "GetClients" will not include the AssigneeUser, which I want in that case.

Comment: Why don't you create and use a response model ? It is not about GORM or anything else. You are returning a model.

Comment: @levniko, Yeah, awesome, i didn't thought about it thanks